# Re-arrange data in sql table using pivot

Tags: sql-server

I have data:

```
2014-10-28  Excess   1025   98297654999.82
2014-10-29  Excess   251    1902171582.07
2014-10-28  Pastdue  1590   7645464003.17
2014-10-29  Pastdue  13       3704776.10
```

I need data like this:

```
Date       ExcessCount  ExcessAmt   PassCount   PassAmt
28/10/2015  1025       98297655000     1590     7645464003
29/10/2015  251        1902171582      13       3704776.1
```

Please let me know how to do this.

Comment: Specify Column names for above data

Comment: how date 2014-10-28 changes to 28/10/2015 ??what is the logic behind that ?

Answer (score 5):

Check this out

```
SELECT column1 as date, SUM(ExcessCount) as ExcessCount, SUM(ExcessAmt) as ExcessAmt, SUM(PastdueCount) as PastdueCount, SUM(PastdueAmt) as PastdueAmt
FROM 
(
  select column1,column3,column4, column2+'Count' as tempcol1,column2+'Amt' as tempcol2
  from tablename
) x
pivot
(
  min(column3)
  for tempcol1 in ([ExcessCount], [PastdueCount])
) p
pivot
(
  min(column4)
  for tempcol2 in ([ExcessAmt], [PastdueAmt])
) q
group by column1
```

Put your main table column names at column1, Column2, Column3, Column4

FYI..

[image]

Comment: Hi, Please consider accepting an answer if it solved your problem, so other's can know about it to.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select DateColumn,
sum(case when ExcessColumn = 'Excess' then CountColumn else 0 end) as ExcessCount,
sum(case when ExcessColumn = 'Excess' then AtmColumn else 0 end) as ExcessAmt,
sum(case when ExcessColumn = 'Pastdue' then CountColumn else 0 end) as PassCount,
sum(case when ExcessColumn = 'Pastdue' then AtmColumn else 0 end) as PassAtm
from TableName
group by DateColumn
```

Comment: OP states **using pivot**

Comment: @PravinDeshmukh, may be OP doesn't know that there are other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

**`Instead of Pivot`** ,go for **`Simple Subquery`**:

```
create table #test
(
dates datetime,
descs varchar(10),
value int,
amount varchar(30)
)

insert into #test values('2014-10-28','Excess',1025,'98297654999.82')
insert into #test values('2014-10-29','Excess',251,'1902171582.07')
insert into #test values('2014-10-28','Pastdue',1590,'7645464003.17')
insert into #test values('2014-10-29','Pastdue',13,'3704776.10')

select * from #test


select distinct a.dates
,(select value  from #test b where descs='Excess' and a.dates=b.dates) as 'ExcessCount'
,(select amount from #test b where descs='Excess' and a.dates=b.dates)  as 'ExcessAmt'
,(select value  from #test b where descs='Pastdue'and a.dates=b.dates) as 'PassCount',
(select amount  from #test b where descs='Pastdue'and a.dates=b.dates)  as 'PassAmt'
from #test a
```

Output:

```
dates                    ExcessCount    ExcessAmt     PassCount    PassAmt
2014-10-28 00:00:00.000     1025      98297654999.82    1590     7645464003.17
2014-10-29 00:00:00.000      251          1902171582.07       13     3704776.10
```